# Eclipse package explorer empty

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

I'm new to Eclipse, and I can't seem to get the package explorer to cooperate.  Here is my current file tree:

```
└───workspace
    ├───bin
    │   └───var
    ├───res
    │   └───gui
    └───src
        └───var
            └───all of my source code
```

I attempted to start a workspace in the current tree, \workspace, \workspace\src, and workspace\src\var.  All resulted in an empty package explorer.  I have tried Eclipse Indigo, Juno, Classic Indigo, and Classic Juno, with no success.  Can anyone offer help?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It seems you are trying to force Eclipse to work in a way it wasn't designed. A `workspace` in Eclipse should be a directory in which you hold your projects. You should start with an empty workspace directory and then create the different projects using Eclipse.

Comment: So you're saying I swap "workspace" with my current directory?

Comment: no, I say create a new directory, point your Eclipse workspace to it, then use Eclipse `New Project` wizard to create your projects.

Comment: Find an IDE suited for yourself. Don't suit yourself for an IDE.

Answer (score 20):

Maybe a little late, but i found a solution to this problem! Just right click on the explorer, select *import*, then in *general* select *Existing project into workspace* then find the root folder of your project and it should import it just fine. Well, worked for me anyways ;)

Comment: This, this, this!
No, not to late. For me this came just in time!
Thanks so much!

Comment: If this helped you (wow, this was almost a year ago... :) ) please accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rightclick on your Project
2. select 'Properties'
3. 'Java Build Path'
4. select tab 'Source'
5. Button 'Add Folder'
6. add your source folder / all your source folders

Comment: I don't see "Java Build Path" on Java Juno.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Probably a separate question, but why did Eclipse not recognize the .project file in the original "workspace" directory?

Comment: @CodeMonkey2 You are confusing the terms "*workspace*" and "*project*". A "*workspace*" it's just a container for projects, your project should be a different folder inside the workspace. Notice that after starting Eclipse your "*workspace*" contains a `.metadata` folder and no `.project` or `.classpath` file.

Comment: My tree included only the folders, but the .project and .classpath files were there.