# Package Explorer in Eclipse stuck in resources

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

At work we are using Eclipse Java EE Indigo Service Release 2 (build id: 20120216-1857) and I'm having some difficulty with my package explorer. It seems like it's drilled into a mysterious "resources" directory and I cannot do anything to get out of it and see my packages. I've had to switch to using Project Explorer for some time but I just prefer Package Explorer. Can anyone assist with this? I've included an image:

[image: Stuck in resources]

I've attempted to link with Editor, reset perspectives, close and re-open perspectives, but nothing changes. I haven't tried re-installing but I'd really like to avoid having to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the logs in the workspace folder show anything potentially related? Or some "pid" files in the Eclipse installation folder?

Comment: There are complaints about:
`Links indexer could not remove old database files and has disabled itself. Please close this program, remove the directory C:\dev\trunk\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.etools.references, and restart this program again.`
I did so and restarted Eclipse and it seemed to satisfy the error, but no solution to my issue

Comment: Googling "Eclipse Package Explorer empty" shows f.ex. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13992661/2814308) and other. Maybe it helps. You could also try to create a new workspace.